# Django urls.py runs only once. Why? How does it call views on next request?

Tags: python, django

While testing django cashing on our development server, one of our senior asked if is it possible to change the value of caching timeout on `urls.py` without restarting the http service.

On first note, I was 100% sure it can be done by changing the timeout value dynamically.

For example - As suggested by my other colleague, If we save the timeout value in separate xml file and read this file value in urls.py and assign that value on the caching command, then by changing the value in the xml file, caching timeout will be updated without restarting the http service.

But when we tested this, we came to an understanding that it works only on first hit as the `urlpattern object` is passed to django server and `urls.py` never runs again unless the http service is restarted.

In the end to get our requirement done, we had to write few more script inside the view function to load the urls.py again so that it reads the new caching timeout value.

So my question is why this urls.py is not loaded every time on every url hit but only once on first time?, where does this urlpattern object goes?, Any Idea!

Comment: Probably because there's a reasonable expectation that `urls.py` does not get modified on a regular basis.  If this file is being changed often, I'd re-examine your development strategy.

Comment: I know that `urls.py` is does not get modified on a regular basis and that's why Django Team has made it load only once. 

My question is where this `urlpattern` object is passed and which function or class is responsible for this. I want to understand the object flow structure.

Answer (score 2):

It's not passed anywhere, but it is *imported* only once. Python runs a module when it is imported, and after that it is just kept in memory. Django can access the urlpatterns variable in the module whenever it once, the module isn't re-run.

That's not specific to Django or urls.py, it's just how Python modules work.

Comment: Or as commonly known: `Singleton` pattern

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#performance), I found this after searching the Django repository for `re.compile`. Look through [django.core.urlresolvers](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py). RegexURLResolver is called on the root urlconf unless it's set by whatever calls `get_resolver`. The output of `get_resolver`, and therefore the result of building the URL resolver, is cached:

```
@lru_cache.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_resolver(urlconf):
if urlconf is None:
    from django.conf import settings
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
return RegexURLResolver(r'^/', urlconf)
```

`re.compile` is called twice in the `RegexURLResolver` class. You may want to look further into that, and the `@lru_cache` decorator, for whatever it is you want to do.